# Why did I get a "None" value of the parameter in subclass?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, class, subclass

I'm new to python (and coding) and I've been trying to expand my knowledge by youtube tutorials. When watching a chapter about classes I have created a class and a sub class and I don't know why I get the results as they are. Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, height):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

    def print_info(self):
        print(self.name + ", age " + self.age + ", height " + self.height + "cm.")


class Employee(Person):
    def  __init__(self, name, age, height, id_number):
        Person.__init__(self, name, age, height)
        self.id_number = id_number

    def print_employee_info(self):
        print(str(Person.print_info(self)) + self.id_number)

john = Employee("John", "20", "182", "2230")
john.print_employee_info()
```

I expected it to print:

```
"John, age 20, height 182cm.2230"
```

What I got is:

```
"John, age 20, height 182cm 
None2230"
```

So I believe it that it prints in new line "None2230" because I call the method Person.print_info(self) ?

What I don't know is why there is "None" added to id_number and how can I fix this?

If anything else bothers you, just write it down I'd like to learn.

Thanks a lot for the answers.

Much appreciated.

Comment: `print_info` returns `None`.  So `str(Person.print_info(self))` results in the string `"None"`.

Comment: Does it return 'None' because "john" is not a "Person"?

Comment: No, it returns `None` because that is the default behavior of a function when there is no `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your `print_info` method to return a string rather than printing it. Try changing it to this:

```
    def print_info(self):
        return self.name + ", age " + self.age + ", height " + self.height + "cm."
```

Then your `print_employee_info` can just be

```
    def print_employee_info(self):
        print(self.print_info() + self.id_number)
```

Comment: And if it's returning a string, it probably shouldn't be called `print_info`. (It's probably a reasonable definition of `__str__`, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Both your `print_*` methods look like they should be converted to `__str__` methods.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, *, name, age, height, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}, age {self.age}, height {self.height} cm'


class Employee(Person):
    def  __init__(self, *, id_number, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.id_number = id_number

    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__() + self.id_number


john = Employee(name="John", age="20", height="182", id_number="2230")
print(john)
```

Try to push I/O "up" as far as possible in your code. If your method can return a string for someone else to print rather than printing it itself, do it.

Comment: Didn't make it to the super function. I heard it is very useful, but not quite there yet with my youtube tutorial. So thanks for the help, but i do not yet understand the code above. Will be there in a couple of weeks (i hope)

Answer (score 0):

print_info(self) does not return anything (returns None).
If you want your code to work you should do soemthing like:

```
def get_info(self):
    return self.name + ", age " + self.age + ", height " + self.height + "cm."
```

and then

```
def get_employee_info(self):
    return str(Person.print_info(self)) + self.id_number
```

Finally, to use this, call:

```
print(john.get_employee_info())
```

Comment: You are wrong about including `self` in the call. Either you need to call `Person.print_info(self)` or `self.print_info()`. The way you have written it will raise a TypeError.